# Как использовать БД из сети в андроид приложении

Tags: java, android, база-данных

Есть сайт, на нём будет БД пользователей, пока не знаю, какая именно, сайт не мною создаётся.
Моя задача, написать приложение, которое будет использовать всё те же данные пользователей (логин, пароль, другие данные типа виртуальной валюты), как мне:
1) Получить данные, что бы залогинить пользователя и потом использоват их
2) Менять данные, если пользователь поменяет что-то через приложение в своём профиле или приобретёт за виртуальную валюту.

Comment: Если бэкенд будут писать адекватные люди, то ни с какой БД вы работать не будете - вам будет предоставлен REST API и вы будете слать обычные HTTP-запросы. Чтобы понять в общих чертах как это делается - посмотрите исходники любого клиента к любому сайту. Ну а конкретика будет только после предоставления API. А пока ваш вопрос слишком абстрактный, чтобы дать ответ и его скорее всего закроют.